# Does Tegra K1 support RenderScript on GPU?

Tags: nvidia, renderscript, tegra

Does Tegra K1 support RenderScript on GPU ? I used Mipad and wrote a sample RS kernel and ran it, but the cpu usage can reach 95% on average. Kernel like this:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.android.rs.hellocomputendk)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

void root(const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out) {
  v_out->xyzw = v_in->xyzw;
}
```

The allocation's flag like this:
RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SHARED | RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SCRIPT,

Official pdf said Tegra K1 GPU support RS, i don't know where i am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the GPU utilization? You could try [nVidia nSight Tegra](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-tegra).

The high CPU utilization is per core or per processor? If per processor this might indicate that RS has parallelized the task among cores.

Are you using [Tegra Android Development Pack](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack)?

It may be that nVidia supports RenderScript just for the CPU side. Since K1 has a CUDA based GPU, the logic for putting any type of code on the GPU may not be implemented.

GPU may be used in kernels that do image processing stuff like [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/levels-in-renderscript.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am using Tegra Android Development Pack, official said K1 GPU supports CUDA, RenderScript, OpenCL, OpenGL, so i  try to use it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sure. However if they say that K1 GPU supports render script that does not necessarily mean that you can launch any kernel type on it. It could only be limited to image processing kernels where you allocate memory in the texture / vertex space.